# $.ajax success function wait

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Due to the (my perceived) nature of the `$.ajax GET` I'm not sure what I'm looking for is possible in this method, but thought I should ask as it's causing me some trouble. I am in no way an expert on JS, apologies if this is obvious, the title is poor, couldn't think of a different way to say it.

**What I'm doing** - using `$.ajax` to get values from the back-end API functions (these work). In the `success` property I'm using an anonymous function to pass more data across that would not otherwise be brought back. When stepping through the console breakpoints in the Chrome console the success function is often skipped as it's not brought back quick enough.

**What I would like** - in the example below, I don't want `getStuff` to complete, before its success `DoSomething` has returned, as I'm missing loads of data from the API which I need to pass through to `DoSomething` - is this possible to achieve?

**Example**

```
function getStuff(id, hid) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/api/GetMyStuff/" + id,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (vData) {
            DoSomething(vData, id, hid); // not always being hit
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Take a look at https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `async` option and set it to `false` to get a synchronous call:

```
function getStuff(id, hid) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/api/GetMyStuff/" + id,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false, // HERE
        success: function (vData) {
            DoSomething(vData, id, hid); // not always being hit
        }
    });
}
```

But **that is not a good way to do ajax request**, you should rethink your code organization (like giving a callback function to your `getStuff` method and calling it in the `success` callback).

Comment: Don't take the 'a' out of ajax. ;-)

Comment: This is generally not advisable. This blocks the main event loop, which causes laggy behavior for the user while the request itself is pending.

Comment: @jmar777 That's exactly what I stated in the end of my (updated) answer.

Comment: @Holt - thanks for the explanation, everything rides on the data that is brought back from the api to form charts, this will be done every five minutes or so, if setting `async: false` is bad practice; what would you suggest?

Comment: @Holt +1 for the update. Not a biggie, but "You need to [...]" might set a better tone with "You *could*...". /two-cents

Comment: @PurpleSmurph It really depends on what your `DoSomething` function does and what you are doing « after » the ajax call in your current script.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is impossible. Asynchronicity is "leaky", meaning that any asynchronous action requiring a callback (e.g., `$.ajax()`) necessarily forces asynchronous control flow all the way up the call chain.

Please note that in the near future (thanks to `async/await` in ES7), this situation gets a little better.  The asynchronicity is still leaky, but the new keywords make the refactoring scenario a little easier than hand-jamming callbacks everywhere.

Comment: Damn, what I thought then, thank you, where I've called the function `DoSomething`, is the data from that anonymous method lost or will it be brought through later? Trying to get used to the Chrome console and what it can/can't do.

Comment: If `DoSomething()` isn't always invoked in your current code, that probably means there was an error. I'd recommend also adding a `error: function() {}` handler to your `$.ajax()` configuration.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be - the Id that's brought through, and parsed into the `getStuff`function, works on the API call if I directly channel it. There will be more error handling code but that doesn't seem to be the issue. The Ids that fail are random, they're never the same, which is why I believe the ajax call is finishing before the function has time to return.